# Laravel Echo causing post routes to fail

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

The application works fine when I DON'T specify Laravel Echo in `bootstrap.js`.

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~2.6",
},
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "laravel-echo": "^1.3.2",
    "pusher-js": "^4.1.0",
}
```

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'app-key',
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});
```

broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'eu',
        'encrypted' => true
    ],
],
```

I am on my localhost, and have tried following multiple tutorials and many variations but none have solved the problem. The application loads all the get api routes correctly, but when I try to login I get a 500 error.

I am also using Vue & VueRouter in case that has any influence.

**EDIT**

It seems that something is interfering with the CsrfToken sent with axios. If I rearrange my bootstrap.js file so that Echo is imported BEFORE axios:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
etc.

window.axios = require('axios');
```

The post routes work perfectly but I can't listen to any events when I submit them via an axios post route (if I submit an event by an Artisan console command it works fine and I can listen to the response and output it to the console).

If I `dd('test')` in the event Constructor, the post route outputs `test`.
If I `dd('test')` in the broadcastOn method, the post route doesn't hit this function.

Comment: Try this one: Uncomment `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,` line in `config > app.php` file and have you specify your PUSHER_APP_ID, PUSHER_APP_KEY and PUSHER_APP_SECRET in .env file?

Comment: I have already un-commented it and my `.env` file is set up correctly as the event works fine using a console command.

Comment: Next step is to check out your cluster information in Pusher. In my case, it is `mt1` instead of `eu`. You can find a cluster information in pusher dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar problem, the solution: don't use Laravel Echo.

Remove Echo and instead directly pull in Pusher (`https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js`) before your main application js. Then at the bottom of the `bootstrap.js` file:

```
window.Pusher = new Pusher('app-key', {
    cluster: 'your-cluster',
    encrypted: (true/false),
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': token.content
        }
    }
});
```

Now you can do something similar to the following:

```
var channel = Pusher.subscribe('channel-name');
channel.bind('broadcast-event-name', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to import `pusher-js` before `laravel-echo`.

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
```